# jquery ajax is loading entire external html rather than targeted div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple ajax request loading in an external html file but it's pulling in the entire page rather than just the specific div I requested. Does this only work using the .load?

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 't3.html #test',
 success: function(data) {
 $('.incoming').append(data);
 }
 });
```

Comment: neither of those seemed to work, perhaps the second tip wont work because I am working on localhost/tomcat

Comment: passing the filter parameter works only with load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `load()` method which will filter the external page for the selector you want

```
$('.incoming').load('t3.html #test');
```

Otherwise using other AJAX methods you would need to create your own filter, they do not parse the url for the content themselves:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 't3.html',
    success: function(data) {
        var div=$(data).find(' #test'); /* if #test not wrapped in parent use filter instead of find*/
        $('.incoming').append(div);
    }
});
```

Refernce: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I tried your second snippet, but it doesn't work. Checked in firebug, and there are no errors. Your comment def helps though, just need to figure out what Im missing.

Comment: depends on structure of other page . If `#test` is not wrapped in `body` try `filter` instead of `find`

Comment: logic is standard jQuery traversal methods. If `find()` didn't work, made sense you had a partial html page and isn't unusual to do that for ajax content